# Django prompt the user for login in class based view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a class based view which lets a user to add a product to the cart, but the user should be logged in. I have used `LoginRequiredMixin` to restrict the access to `AddToCart` CBV, but the product page can be viewed by everyone. I would like to prompt the user asking them to login in whenever they click `Add To Cart` button and when they are logged in then only they can add product to their respective cart.

```
class AddToCart(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    """
        Add an item to the cart
    """
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        print(slug)
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
        order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
            item=item,
            user=self.request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        print(order_qs)
        if order_qs.exists():
            order = order_qs[0]
            if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug):
                pass
                # message : Item already in cart
            else:
                order.items.add(order_item)
                # message : Item was added to cart
                return redirect("products:product")
        else:
            ordered_date = timezone.now()
            order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
            order.items.add(order_item)
            # message : Item was added to cart
            return redirect("products:product")
```

A possible solution; I can remove `LoginRequiredMixin` and check for `request.user` and if it says `AnonymousUser` I can return a message via `Django Message Framework` and display the message to user. But this doesn't sound like a good solution. Another work around can be using `{% if not user.is_authenticated %}` in template and showing some messages like `To add product you need to login` while `LoginRequiredMixin` remains intact. But my home page also shows a list of product which has a `Add To Cart` icon on every product, this solution will definitely not work for home page.   Any thoughts are welcomed.

For front-end I am using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a decorator which will redirect to login page, if user is not logged in.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def authtenticate_users():

    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_anonymous:
                return redirect('account_login')
            else:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(authtenticate_users(), name="get")
class AddToCart(TemplateView):
```

**UPDATE:**
Finally what I ended up using is `login_required` decorator on my CBV.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="get")
class AddToCart(TemplateView):
```

Reason being `login_required` automatically redirects to last page before login was initiated.

Answer (score 0):

How about his approach:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %} 
To add product to cart, you need to <a href="/login">login</a>
<style>
 .addToCartIcon {
   display: none;
  }
</style>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It will work fine on product specific page or product detail page. But on my home page, products are displayed as a list of bootstrap cards, which has a button `Add to cart` and if  I do this every card will have link to `login` page as well as `Add to cart`. Which wouldn't look great.